# vscode c++ debugger include path configuration

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, makefile, gdb

**TL;DR:**

**How to include c++ source files/headers for debugger(gdb) in vscode (using "includePath" in c_cpp_properties.json not working)?**

**Context:**

I am using vscode on Ubuntu 18.04 and developing a C++ opensource project built by Makefiles. I can successfully build the project using Makefiles, and the binary called "target" is generated in /src directory, along with most of source files in the same directory. I am lanching the vscode debugger using following configuration:
`launch.json`

```js
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/target",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true,
                    "directory": "/src"
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

`c_cpp_properties.json`

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "gnu11",
            "cppStandard": "gnu++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "${default}",
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Everything went fine, the debugger stopped at the break point set in .cpp files located under /src. But when I try to step into a function whose source files located in other directories like `/usr/include/`, the debugger can't step into that file.
I am guessing it's because the compiler don't include the `/usr/include/` or "the debug symbols and source path" compiled to the binary mismatched with the actual source path. I have tried to include `/usr/include/` in `includePath` in `c_cpp_properties.json` but that don't work actually. So I am wondering what I should do next?

**P.S.**

In addition to this question. I feel like the vscode file include process is just a black box. Nowadays I
just see there is a `includePath` property under `c_cpp_properties.json`, which is intended to be used by intelliSense engine, not by compiler or debugger. And I don't see any similar include option for tasks.json(compiler) and launch.json(debugger). The wiredest thing is that even if I leave `includePath` empty, intellisense can still find the source files located in some famous directory like `/usr/include`, `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/` where compiler and debugger can't. I am wondering if there is an official documents systematically document how include process works in vscode?

Comment: The c_cpp_properties.json is just for configuring IntelliSense functionality.
To configure additional source files for the gdb debugger you need to configure this via a gdbinit file. The ~/.gdbinit is loaded per default so this would be a good place.